# Agenda de clientes con python

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy con un ejercicio de varias fases donde tengo que hacer una agenda de clientes con distintas opciones(añadir clientes,listar,borrar.....etc),estoy en los primeros pasos del ejercicio y tengo que incrustar una función que añada y pregunte una serie de conceptos y los almacene (en un diccionario he supuesto), la eda tiene que estar entre 18 y 99 y tiene que ser numérico, aligual que el salario. Lo que llevo es esto

```
clientes={}
def menu():
    print ('(1)' 'Anadir un cliente:')
    print ('(2)' 'listar clientes:')
    print ('(3)' 'Borrar cliente:')
    print ('(4)' 'Grabar datos en el fichero:')
    print ('(5)' 'Leer datos de fichero:')
    print ('(99)' 'Finalizar')
    while True:
        opcion=int(input('Introducir numero, siguiente opcion: '))
        if opcion==1:
            def ficha():
                print ('Ha introducido la opcion añadir cliente')
                edad=' '
                clientes['NIF']=input('Introduce el NIF del usuario: ')
                clientes['Apellido']=input('Introduce el apellido del usuario: ')
                clientes['Nombre']=input('Introduce el nombre del usuario: ')
                if 18<=edad<=99:
                    clientes['Edad']=int(input('Introduce la edad: '))
                clientes['Salario']=int(input('Introduce el salario: '))
                print (clientes)
                return
            ficha()
    
        
    elif opcion==2:
        print ('Ha introducido la opcion listar clientes')
    elif opcion==3:
        print ('Ha introducido la opcion borrar cliente')
    elif opcion==4:
        print ('Ha introducido la opcion grabar datos en el fichero')
    elif opcion==5:
        print ('Ha introducido la opcion leer datos del fichero')
    elif opcion==99:
        print ('Finalizado')
        break
    else:
        print ('Ha introducido una opcion erronea')

    return
menu()
```

El error que me da es el siguiente.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-f6ff07912ade> in <module>
     36         else:
     37             print ('Ha introducido una opcion erronea')
---> 38 menu()

<ipython-input-6-f6ff07912ade> in menu()
     20                 print (clientes)
     21                 return
---> 22             ficha()
     23 
     24             print ('Ha introducido la opcion añadir cliente')

<ipython-input-6-f6ff07912ade> in ficha()
     15                 clientes['Apellido']=input('Introduce el apellido del usuario: ')
     16                 clientes['Nombre']=input('Introduce el nombre del usuario: ')
---> 17                 if 18<=edad<=99:
     18                     clientes['Edad']=int(input('Introduce la edad: '))
     19                 clientes['Salario']=int(input('Introduce el salario: '))

TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Si alguien me puede echar una mano se lo agradecería,saludos

Comment: Los `elif` los tienes fuera del bucle `while`, tienes que indentarlo a partir del primero de ellos para que queden a la misma altura.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que para comprobar la edad en el `input` del usuario sería más útil utilizar rangos, como este:

```
if edad in range(18,100)
```

Con ello compruebas que el valor de la variable `edad` se encuentra en el rango establecido entre paréntesis. El `input` que pregunta la edad, debería ir fuera del condicional, ya que no tiene sentido preguntar la edad dentro del bucle, ya que previamente a la ejecución del `if`la variable edad no tiene valor alguno.

También te recomiendo, como ha dicho Fran, que revises las tabulaciones ya que como la mayoría de lenguajes, `python` es sensible a ellas y en el ejemplo que facilitas los `elif` no están alineados con el primer `if`.

Tu código quedaría tal que así:

```
clientes={}

def ficha():

    print ('Ha introducido la opcion añadir cliente')
    clientes['NIF']=input('Introduce el NIF del usuario: ')
    clientes['Apellido']=input('Introduce el apellido del usuario: ')
    clientes['Nombre']=input('Introduce el nombre del usuario: ')
    edad = clientes['Edad']=int(input('Introduce la edad: '))

    while edad not in range(18,100):
        print("Edad fuera del rango")
        edad = clientes['Edad']=int(input('Introduce la edad: '))

        if edad in range(18,100):
            print (clientes)
            break


def menu():
    print ('(1)' 'Anadir un cliente:')
    print ('(2)' 'listar clientes:')
    print ('(3)' 'Borrar cliente:')
    print ('(4)' 'Grabar datos en el fichero:')
    print ('(5)' 'Leer datos de fichero:')
    print ('(99)' 'Finalizar')

    while True:
        opcion=int(input('Introducir numero, siguiente opcion: '))
        
        if opcion==1:           
            ficha()       
        elif opcion==2:
            print ('Ha introducido la opcion listar clientes')
        elif opcion==3:
            print ('Ha introducido la opcion borrar cliente')
        elif opcion==4:
            print ('Ha introducido la opcion grabar datos en el fichero')
        elif opcion==5:
            print ('Ha introducido la opcion leer datos del fichero')
        elif opcion==99:
            print ('Finalizado')
            break
        else:
            print ('Ha introducido una opcion erronea')

        return
menu()
```

Y un ejemplo de su ejecución puede ser este:

```
(1)Anadir un cliente:
(2)listar clientes:
(3)Borrar cliente:
(4)Grabar datos en el fichero:       
(5)Leer datos de fichero:
(99)Finalizar
Introducir numero, siguiente opcion: 1
Ha introducido la opcion añadir cliente
Introduce el NIF del usuario: 123
Introduce el apellido del usuario: Perez
Introduce el nombre del usuario: Juan
Introduce la edad: 10
Edad fuera del rango
Introduce la edad: 15
Edad fuera del rango
Introduce la edad: 20
{'NIF': '123', 'Apellido': 'Perez', 'Nombre': 'Juan', 'Edad': 20}
```

Comment: Una pregunta, el if con la edad tendría que ir encima de la entrada en el diccionario de la edad, no?

Comment: Preguntar el valor de una variable después de operar con ella no tiene ejecución alguna, ya que estas comprobando el valor de una cosa que aún no lo tiene.

Comment: Disculpa pero no lo pillo, la pregunta (el if) entiendo yo que la hago antes de operar con ella (al introducirla en el diccionario), entonces pienso que debe ir encima de la entrada del diccionario y ésta, debajo de ella indentada.(lo he probado ahora con un for in range y no para de pedirme la edad)

Comment: No entiendo lo que pides. ¿Quieres comprobar la edad del usuario sin darle un valor? ¿Por qué no quieres que te pida la edad? ¿Cuándo debe pedirla?

Comment: Es la condición para que acepte la edad, si no, debería mandar un mensaje de error y volver a preguntar al usuario, por eso me lío, aparte, esta última parte será con un try y una excepción pero no domino las excepciones aún. Me estoy liando

Comment: Una condición comprobando ¿que?, en tu código en ningún momento indicas el valor de la edad, por eso te da error en ese punto. Nunca podrás saber si la edad del usuario se encuentra en ese rango si no le preguntas la edad.

Comment: Ok, pillado, he hecho un cambio, if not in range(18,99): después de introducir la edad para que me dé un mensaje de error si la edad no está en ese rango y me vuelva a preguntar, pero no lo hace, de todas formas muchas, la parte primera me he terminado enterando

Comment: `range(18, 99)` solo incluirá los números desde el 18 al 98. Viendo que ha puesto en su código `if 18<=edad<=99`, se entiende que el 99 también debería incluirse, por lo que debería ser: `range(18, 100)`

Comment: Para que te muestre un error si introduces una edad errónea, añade un `else` con un mensaje y vuelve a llamar a la función.

Comment: Y en realidad, la variable `edad` si que tiene valor, la ha declarado como `edad=' '`, por eso está dando el error al intentar compararla con números, ya que es tipo `string`.

Comment: No tiene un valor válido.

Comment: Revisa la respuesta, a ver si ahora se adapta a lo que indicas.

Answer (score -1):

Tu error:

```
            edad=' '
            clientes['NIF']=input('Introduce el NIF del usuario: ')
            clientes['Apellido']=input('Introduce el apellido del usuario: ')
            clientes['Nombre']=input('Introduce el nombre del usuario: ')
            if 18<=edad<=99:
```

Primero asignas espacios a `edad`, luego, sin haber cambiado su contenido (¿faltara un input?), la comparas con valores numéricos.

**Diagnóstico**

Falta un

```
edad = int(input("Intrdocue la edad del usuario"))
```